# How to bind a collection with objects?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to bind a collection of objects from a querystring, but I cannot find the proper querystring format.

My controller code:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public void Get(IEnumerable<Filter> filters)
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: Why are you binding to a collection? Wouldn't the `Filter.Name` values all be different, and well-known beforehand?

Comment: The Filter class has more properties. I just simplified it for the sake of the demo. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to pass the objects with querystring you could try as below:

```
https://localhost:44389/Test/Index?filters[0].Name=n1&filters[1].Name=n2&filters[2].Name=n3&filters[2].Value=v3
```

The result:
[image]
[image]

the offcial document related:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#collections

but i don't think it's a good solution,because the length of Url is limited,if your model has plenty properties and your collection has many elements ,you may get some error

Comment: It's working, but you right. The lenght of the query could be to big. What would you recommend ? Are there any other formats?

Comment: If your could post a request,set the collection in the form could help